# Animated webp in Nextjs Image Component shows all frames only on mobile

Tags: next.js, next.js13, webp, nextjs-image

An animated webp in Nextjs Image Component does not clean up frames after they've been rendered (resulting in all frames being shown by the end of the animation). Seems doubtful that the bug is with iOS safari & mobile chrome, but rather a bug in the nextjs Image Component. Anyone have a solution or seen this before?